# Tinder APIs are not working

Tags: ios, api, tinder

I want to update my location using the url https://api.gotinder.com/user/ping and sending data with post method and data is {"lat":xxxxxx,"lon":xxxxxxx} with all the headers explained in the post below. But it is not updating my location. and giving me a result {"status":"401","error":""}. is this API still working? Or the link is changed.

i am using this link to call APIs https://gist.github.com/rtt/10403467

Please help me.
Thanks

Comment: This isn't an official API by any means, the author says in the first sentence that he reverse engineered the API by sniffing network traffic while using the app.

Comment: Your token is incorrect or doesn't match the app ID

Answer (score 0):

HTTP Status 401 means "Unauthorized". You are using the API without authorization. Check with the Tinder developer documentation to see what options you have for authorization when using their API. You probably need some kind of access token.